# Identifying a power transistor (>24 V, >0.75 A)

Tags: transistors, identification

I need help identifying this power transistor. From what I understand, they must be either NPN bipolar or N-channel FET/IGBTs, because the device is a low side LED-driver with common anode. The maximum voltage is 24V and the transistors probably are capable to switch bigger voltages.

The whole device can switch 75W at24V and there are 4 of these semiconductors, hence each of them should be able to drive 0.75 A at least.

[image: circuit with transistors] Sorry for the poor image quality, was done with my old samsung G SII through a scale magnifier.

gate/base is probably the lower left pin. The via leads over a 330 Ohms resistor to the Y of an AND-gate (ACT108) on the other side of the PCB.

I wasn't even able to locate the manufacturer (ViC ????) let alone the device itself (I266DN AE 13) in da intarrnet.

**edit**
I forgot to mention, why I want to know the model of this part, and if possible, the name of the manufacturer. I want to know the reliability of the whole device. There are some electrolyte capacitors which could limit the lifetime, but they aren't in a thermal stressed section and are well oversized. The manufacturer says it has only 20000 hours lifetime, and I was thinking that these possibly crappy transistors could contribute to the short lifetime.

Comment: The "I266" in the top marking is actually a "1266".

Comment: Although I found this tiny company VIC Semi , they only advertise passive parts like TVS. So it seems to be an unreliable source of clone packaged chips.  Judging by the circuit, it seems to be a 10A Nch FET in a fullwave PWM  bridge with boost diode cap voltage for high side with 0.2/4 Ohm current sense R's implying 1.5A for a 75mV shunt. So consider Ids ratings at 10x this current with RdsOn< 50 mOhm.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It is not a PWM bridge. The device is a 4 ch LED dimmer and there are only 4 transistors, so it can't be a bridge, can it?

Comment: You can choose any similar logic level Nch FET rated for low RdsOn

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Ok, I see I forgot to explain, why I wanted to know the model and manufacturer. I added some notes to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an educated guess, but it's likely a clone of the AOB266L which is an N channel Trench MOSFET in TO-263 package like the ones in your picture.

Full datasheet: http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AOB266L.pdf

There is also a company called VIC Semiconductor: http://vicsemi.com/ but their website shows no mention of them making this device.

Comment: Either that or it's a clone of the 2SD1266 in a different package. The circuit would also match that.